# How close are we to knowing the rate of convergence to $0$ of $\prod_{p\le x}(1-1/p)^{-1}-e^\gamma\log x $?

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers, asymptotics, conjectures

This is a question related to an earlier one of mine, which I may answer myself eventually, as I have learnt more about the topic.

Despite what one can read on the [MathWorld page about Mertens' third theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensTheorem.html), in 2009 [Diamond and Pintz showed](http://jtnb.cedram.org/cedram-bin/article/JTNB_2009__21_3_523_0.pdf)$$\underset{p\ \text{prime}}{\prod_{p\le x}}\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{-1}-e^\gamma\log x=\Omega_{\pm}\left(\frac{\log\log\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\right);$$on the other hand, by a theorem of Dusart, for all $x\ge2973$ $$\left\lvert\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{-1}-e^\gamma\log x\right\rvert <\frac{0.2}{\log x}.$$ In the end of 2014, using a probabilistic argument, [Lamzouri conjectured](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3777v1)

$$\left\lvert\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{-1}-e^\gamma\log x\right\rvert \sim \frac{e^\gamma}{2\pi}\frac{(\log\log\log x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}.$$ Has it been established that$$-\infty<\liminf_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{(\log\log\log x)^2}\left(\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{-1}-e^\gamma\log x\right)<0 \ ?$$I googled quite a lot, but I could find nothing. Has there been no progress yet?

Comment: Is that last inequality your conjecture?

Comment: @Nicco: It ought to be, I suppose.

Comment: @ Vincent Oliva : When making a conjecture on this site it's crucial to put more details on what led you to speculate that your conjecture is true,it helps other users to solve the problem easily if possible.

Comment: @Nicco: Well, what you say is true. But mine is just a refinement of Lamzouri's conjecture, so there's not much more to say than his own probabilistic argument.